# Loading an unsigned assembly dynamically from a signed assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a strong named assembly, AssemblyA.  I want to reference AssemmblyB, which is not strongly named.  What is the best way to do this?

I saw some examples about loading AssemblyB into a separate AppDomain but I ran into some trouble.  Below is what I tried (this code is from within AssemblyA):

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomainName");
var pathToDll = @"\\myDLLs\AssemblyB.dll";
var tmp = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, TYPE_NAME);
```

Now, I am not sure what to use for TYPE_NAME.  I want to be able to use multiple different types from AssemblyB so I'm pretty sure I am on the wrong track here.

One other thing is that I cannot even reference AssemblyB from AssemblyA because once I do, AssemblyA will fail to build due to the strong name/no strong name mismatch.

Do I need to somehow reference AssemblyB from a new, unsigned project?

Basically the goal is to have access to AssemblyB as it I just referenced it directly.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Make sure the calling app allows unsigned assemblies to run.  Possibly, you could do this at runtime, and then only dynamically load AssemblyB when it's OK by the app.  See Assembly.Load(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Any TYPE_NAME you want to access cross AppDomain should be remotable. Check [AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx)
2. Not allowing reference unsigned assemblies from signed assemblies is expected. Otherwise it would beat the purpose of having assembly A signed in the first place.